# Is every element of $\mathrm{SL}(n,R)$ of finite order diagonalizable?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, linear-algebra, algebraic-groups

Let $k>0$ be an integer, let $R$ be a ring (commutative, unital), which contains $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. with a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\to R$) and all $k$-roots of unity. The examples I have in mind are polynomial rings over $\mathbb{C}$.

Is every element of $\mathrm{SL}(n,R)$ of order $k$ diagonalizable?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "contains all $k$-th roots of unity"? Perhaps I am missing something but: Consider $R:=\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ with componentwise addition and multiplication. It has a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ and contains ``all'' $k$-th roots of unity (well, enough to split $t^k-1$ into linear factors). Now let $m:=\begin{pmatrix} (1,1) & (0,1) \\ (0,0) & (1,1)\end{pmatrix}$. Clearly $m$ is invertible, has determinant $1_R=(1,1)$ and order $k$; but it is not diagonalizable.
Perhaps you want to require a bit more?

Comment: @MaxHorn: Probably Jeremy wants his rings to be unital, and he wants his ring homomorphisms to preserve $1$.  There is no ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to your ring that preserves $1$.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant. I edited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. One way to see this is to decompose the group ring $R[G],$ where $G$ is a cyclic group of order $k$, into the product of simple rings. It follows from your assumptions that this is possible and since $G$ is cyclic, every simple component is isomorphic to $R.$ An $n\times n$ matrix $g$ of order $k$ with entries in $R$ gives rise to an $n$-dimensional representation of $G$ over $R$, or equivalently, an $R[G]$-module that is free of rank $n$ as an $R$-module. By the above decomposition, this module is a direct sum of one-dimensional representations. Translating this into the language of matrices, we get an eigenbasis for $g$ and hence $g$ is diagonalizable over $R.$

Comment: This argument only decomposes the representation as a direct sum of projective submodules on which $G$ acts via a character. These submodules need not be free, so the question is: what does "diagonalizable" mean?  

For instance, assume there is a nontrivial invertible $R$-module $L$ such that $E:=L\oplus L\cong R^2$. Then the endomorphism of $E$ which is $1$ (resp. $-1$) on the first (resp. second) factor $L$ is not diagonalizable in the naive sense.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have some explicit example for $E,L,R$ ?